# itext XMLWorkerHelper ignores value attribute of <li> tag

Tags: java, pdf-generation, html-lists, itext, xmlworker

I'm using itext 5.4.5 with XMLWorker 5.4.5 to generate pdf from html that cames from ckEditor.
Users can also paste some text from word documents and this results sometimes in something like this:

```
<ol>
   <li value="3">some text1</li>
</ol>
<div>lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<ol>
   <li value="100">some text2</li>
</ol>
<div>lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<ol>
   <li value="77">some text3</li>
</ol>
```

this results in ckEditor and in html as

```
   3. some text1    
lorem ipsum dolor    
   100. some text2    
lorem ipsum dolor
   77. some text3
```

But if itext convert this html to pdf, it ignores the value of li-tags and sets it to "1." and this results in something like

```
  1. some text1

lorem ipsum dolor

  1. some text2

lorem ipsum dolor

  1. some text3
```

Does somebody knows a way, make itext read and also use the numeric value of a li-tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Numeric value of a li-tag is not working in CKEditor. You can try start option in `<ol>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  
Well, for me works both in CKEditor (3.6.6.1) value attribute in a li tag and start attribute in <ol> tag.
But what doesnt work is the export to pdf with itextpdf and its xmlworker. it just ignores value and also start attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use "start" attribute of `<ol>` tag, like below:

```html
<ol start="3">
  <li>some text1</li>
</ol>
<div>lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<ol start="100">
  <li>some text2</li>
</ol>
```